# DQL query Doctrine not equal returning none result

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT m FROM App\Entity\Message m JOIN m.rejectedby u WHERE u.id != :user AND m.conversation IS NULL');
    $query->setParameter('user',$userid);
```

What is wrong with this query?
I should get results I get nothing instead.

Just to compare similar query with "WHERE u.id = :user" gives results I expect.
User.id to m.rejectedby is many to many relationship.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'I get nothing' - do you get an error response or do you get a null value or 0?

Comment: No error, just an empty array with no hits. I was moving forward by finding a solution with QueryBuilder. This query seems to be fine. I was deceived by other posts with a similar question about not equal usage in DQL. It was probably just the data inconsistency I was querying on. Working solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the QueryBuilder. I hope it will help to someone with a similar problem.

```
$qb1 = $this->createQueryBuilder('m');
    $qb1
        ->select('m')
        ->join('m.rejectedby','u')
        ->andwhere('u.id = :userid')
        ->setParameter('userid',$userid)    
        ;

    
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('ms');
    $qb
        
        ->where($qb->expr()->notIn('ms',$qb1->getDQL()))
        ->setParameter('userid',$userid)
        ->andWhere('ms.conversation IS NULL');
```